# Pokemon Go cuts all audio on boot. Any way to dodge that?

Tags: pokemon-go, android

When I boot up Pokemon Go, doesn't matter what I'm listening to (Podcasts, spotify, etc.) it just pauses it as soon as I see the Niantic/Pokemon Company splash.

Any way to stop this annoying element?

Comment: Have you tried disabling Pokemon Go sounds completely (effects and music)? On iPhone it only stops like this when sound is enabled, but if you disable it then it won't. Not sure about Android.

Comment: Sound is disabled, but still pauses all music as soon as you start the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know ow it only stops it when the app opens. You can just hit play again and you get the sounds from both apps. At least that's how it is for me.

Last night I tried to set Spotify in Offline Mode, then open Pokémon Go and it worked perfectly, at least on Android it seems to work, good luck!